# Javascript/Node check if a loop with callback finish

Tags: javascript, node.js

Exist some way to know if a async loop in node.js (js) finish the last process to execute a new function or send a callback?

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use recursion:

```
do = function(i, data, callback){
    // if the end is reached, call the callback
    if(data.length === i+1)
       return callback()
    obj = data[i]
    doAsync(function(){
        // DO SOMETHING
        i++;
        // call do with the next object
        do(i, data, callback)
    });

}
do(0, [a, b, c], function(){
  THEN DO SOMETHING
});
```

So the same callback will be passed on `do` and when the end is reached, the callback will be executed. This method is quite clean yet if, for example, you need to crawl 50 pages each page will be loaded in a queue, waiting the other to finish before.

Using this function

```
| google.com | yahoo.fr      | SO.com    | github.com | calling callback!
|  (856ms)   | (936ms)       | (787ms)   |  (658ms)   |
```

Without

```
| google.com (1056ms)    | 
| yahoo.fr (1136ms)       |
| SO.com (987ms)        |
| github.com (856ms)   |
```

So another way would to count how many time the async function should be called and each time one is ended, you increment a var, and when said var reached the length, you call the callback.

```
do = function(data, callback){
    var done = 0;
    data.forEach(function(i, value){
       doAsync(function(){
           done++;
           if(done === data.length)
               callback()
       });
    });

}
do(0, [a, b, c], function(){
  THEN DO SOMETHING
});
```

Then it will be

```
| google.com (1056ms)    | 
| yahoo.fr (1136ms)       | calling callback!
| SO.com (987ms)        |
| github.com (856ms)   |
done = 0               1234
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) library. It seems that 'each' iterator would suit your needs.

Comment: I am readin the library, do you have an idea about `eachSeries` , about the iterator and callback declaration? are something like two functions in the declaration of the method?

Comment: async.eachSeries([ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 ], function (prime, callback) {
  console.log(prime);
  callback(); // Alternatively: callback(new Error());
}, function (err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  console.log('Well done :-)!');
});